# Load Test - Constant Load Issue

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2013, error-handling, load-testing

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate for load test. My project is running on visual studio online. I set up 1 for constant load(user number) and select Based on the number of virtual users.

After I run the test, test is aborted and I' m taking the error message:***"VS1550081: Test run execution aborted"***

My test is running correctly for step load from 20 users to 50 users. Why do I take this error on constant load?

Comment: Search for the error code in http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/load-testing-faq-vs

Comment: Done it already. It says "Contact Visual Studio Online support. You will need to give them your test run id".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error results from **exceeding the limit of test results's number**. After I deleted the old test results in the project solution, the error was solved.

Comment: Brilliant solution indeed.